# Powershell | cURL | invalid JSON body in the request

Tags: json, powershell, curl

i'm trying to connect to my server and pass some info via API calls by powershell, but always get JSON error for below command, i'm not able to figure out the issue, i hope if anyone face the same can help..

**original data:**

```
"<If \"%{HTTP:connection} =~ /close/i \">
RequestHeader set connection close
</If>
<ElseIf \"%{HTTP:connection} =~ /keep-alive/i \">
RequestHeader set connection keep-alive
</ElseIf>
<Else>
    RequestHeader set connection close
</Else>"
```

**the Curl command i'm trying:**

```
curl.exe -sk https://10.1.2.209/api/v1/httpd -u test:test23 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH -d \ '{\"include\" : \"<If "%{HTTP:connection} =~ /close/i ">\nRequestHeader set connection close\n</If>\n<ElseIf \"%{HTTP:connection} =~ /keep-alive/i \">\nRequestHeader set connection keep-alive\n</ElseIf>\n<Else>\n RequestHeader set connection close\n</Else>\"}'
```

**error i'm getting**

```
{"code":400,"message":"Found invalid JSON body in the request."
```

Comment: You need to escape the data properly, PowerShell can help with that: `$d = @{include=$dataString} |ConvertTo-Json`, then `curl.exe ... -d $d`

Comment: thnx Mathias, i tried your recommednation:
$body4
{
    "include":  "\u003cIf \\\"%{HTTP:connection} =~ \\/close\\/i \\\"\u003e\\nRequestHeader set connection close\\n\u003c\\/If\u003e\\n\u003cElseIf \\\"%{HTTP:connection} =~ \\/keep-alive\\/i \\\"\u003e\\nRequestHeader set connection keep-alive\\n\u003c\\/ElseIf\u003e\\n\u003cElse\u003e\\n RequestHeader set connection close\\n\u003c\\/Else\u003e"
}
curl.exe -sk https://10.1.2.209/api/v1/httpd -u test:test23 -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PATCH -d  $body4
but still face JSON error, do i miss anything?

Comment: Perhaps you need to let the JSON parser handle escaping `"`, so change `<If \"...\">` to `<If "...">`  (and so on) in the original string

Comment: hey Mathias, still the same, strange!
 $body4
{
    "include":  "\u003cIf \\\"%{HTTP:connection} =~ \\/close\\/i \\\"\u003e\\nRequestHeader set connection close\\n\u003c\\/If\u003e\\n\u003cElseIf \\\"%{HTTP:connection} =~ \\/keep-alive\\/i \\\"\u003e\\nRequestHeader set connection keep-alive\\n\u003c\\/ElseIf\u003e\\n\u003cElse\u003e\\n RequestHeader set connection close\\n\u003c/Else\u003e"

Comment: It doesn't look like you actually removed the slashes from the input string? otherwise the first few characters would be `\u003cIf \"%{H`, not `\u003cIf \\\"%{H`